# Android: Does CountDownTimer still work after the phone gone to sleep

Tags: android, countdowntimer, sleep-mode

Will the CountDownTimer work when the phone gone to sleep mode? If it doesn't, is there a broadcast receiver which I can detect whether the phone gone to sleep and awake again?